# Nothing goes to Printwriter output (which is txt), why?

Tags: java

I have an input txt file that contains mainly strings like this:

> 1. GET:Mark Joseph Maria,1997,BB
> 2. REG:Lukacs Keto,1989
> 3. SET:Lkoaj Mento, 2000"

(the numbers are not in the txt) (so basically the "GET" has 3 string (+ ",") after it, the others just 2) + There are datas that shouldnt be written to my output.txt (thats why I put it in the try block).

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        try {
            String s = input.nextLine();
            String[] line = new String[2];
            line = s.split(":");
            String[] adatok = line [1].split(",");

            switch(line [0]){
                case "REG":
                    insertCustomer(adatok[0], Integer.parseInt(adatok[1]), adatok[2]);
                    break;
                case "GET":
                    withdrawCash(adatok[0], Integer.parseInt(adatok[1]));
                    break;
                case "PUT":
                    depositCash(adatok[0], Integer.parseInt(adatok[1]));
                    break;
                default:
                    input.nextLine();
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            input.nextLine();  
        }
    }
```

You see the methods (insertCustomer, withdrawCash, depositCash) do the "write to the output.txt" thing, but I think the problem is here (I tested the methods and I think they are good). 
Can someone see where I am wrong? I am a noob in Java, so sorry if there is an obvious mistake, but it is my homework and I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Are you getting any runtime or compilation error?

Comment: Maybe an exception is getting swallowed inside the catch block - try to add a log there. Also why are you doing the additional `nextLine` in default and catch? That'd make it skip another line after the first unconditional `nextLine` call.

Comment: By the way, you have "PUT" in `case` statement, but in your example is "SET".

Comment: You expect adatok size = 3 in 'case "reg"' but due to your input example it should be equal to 2

Comment: Please show more code, there is no print writer to be seen in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your PrintWritter is flushed and closed. Sometimes the program ends before it can send its changes to the file.

It doesn't seem to have anything wrong about your code but I would suggest some improvements:

Replace:

```
String[] line = new String[2];
line = s.split(":");
```

with:

```
String[] line = s.split(":");
```

because split will return a new String[], so your call to new String[2] will be wasted.

I also think that you don't want to ignore the lines after the errors. So you shouldn't call `input.nextLine();` on the catch clause or the default one.